# React conditionally execute

Tags: reactjs

I've got the following statement that I'm putting in JSX

I want isURL(props.url) to render only if props.url is defined. isURL causes a crash if props.url is undefined.

```
{props.url && isURL(props.url)}
```

What's the best way of displaying nothing when `props.url` is undefined, and otherwise display `isURL(props.url)`?

Comment: What you have written or `{props.url ? isURL(props.url) : null}` works well.

Comment: What's wrong witht eh solution you used ? I've always been doing the same

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value to a variable before your return.

```
render() {

  var url = '';
  if (typeof this.props.url === 'undefined') {
     url = '';
  }else{
      url = this.props.url;
  }    
  return (
      <div>
       {url}
      </div>    
  );
}
```